# Change to a second language dictionary while readinjg

Tags: iphone

I need a French dictionary as a second choice when I read French text on my iPhone. I am not able to invoke a French dictionary when I select a French word as I do when I am reading English. Is this another case of American exceptionalism? Also there appears to be no way to get to the keyboards when I am reading text. Most awkward indeed!

Answer (score 1):

With the French keyboard activated, type a French word in Notes and then select it and do Define.  Hopefully it will let you download a French reference dictionary.